# Remove any rows where values don't match across specific columns, except if other value(s) is NA

Tags: r, match, subset, na

I am looking for a way to remove any rows where the values across each variable don't match, unless the lack of a match is due to one of the values (or more) being NA.

```
df <- data.frame(uid = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                  x1 = c('a', NA, NA, 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'),
                  x2 = c(NA, 'b', NA, NA, NA, NA, 'b'),
                  x3 = c(NA, NA, 'c', 'a', 'b', NA, 'b'),
                  x4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'b'),
                  x5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'b', 'b'))

df
  uid   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5
1   1    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2   2 <NA>    b <NA> <NA> <NA>
3   3 <NA> <NA>    c <NA> <NA>
4   4    a <NA>    a <NA> <NA>
5   5    a <NA>    b <NA> <NA>
6   6    c <NA> <NA> <NA>    b
7   7    b    b    b    b    b
```

What I am looking for is a method that would remove rows 5 and 6. I tried several methods using subset and was able to get it to work if I did:

```
subset(df, (x1 == x2 | is.na(x1) | is.na(x2)) & ...
           (x4 == x5 | is.na(x4) | is.na(x5)))
```

However, I couldn't find a method that didn't involve typing out every combination, which is already impractical with just 5 columns, but not at all practical given the actual dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution, but I made a function that achieved the result.

#### Libraries

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
```

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(uid = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                 x1 = c('a', NA, NA, 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'),
                 x2 = c(NA, 'b', NA, NA, NA, NA, 'b'),
                 x3 = c(NA, NA, 'c', 'a', 'b', NA, 'b'),
                 x4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'b'),
                 x5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'b', 'b'))
```

#### Code

```
remove_rows <- function(string){
  
  if(sum(is.na(string)) >= (length(string) -1)){
    TRUE
  }else{
    string %>% 
      na.omit() %>% 
      str_c(.,collapse = "") %>% 
      str_count(string) %>% 
      max(na.rm = TRUE) > 1
  }

}

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(remove_rows(c_across(x1:x5)))
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Rowwise: 
    uid x1    x2    x3    x4    x5   
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     NA    NA    NA    NA   
2     2 NA    b     NA    NA    NA   
3     3 NA    NA    c     NA    NA   
4     4 a     NA    a     NA    NA   
5     7 b     b     b     b     b
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lines where the number of unique, non-NA values in columns of interest exceeds 1:

```
df[ ! apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) ) >1, ]
#--------------------
  uid   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5
1   1    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2   2 <NA>    b <NA> <NA> <NA>
3   3 <NA> <NA>    c <NA> <NA>
4   4    a <NA>    a <NA> <NA>
7   7    b    b    b    b    b
```